# Using a Ruby map on a range

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use .map so I don't need to initialize a products array.

Here's the original code:

```
products = []
for page in (1..(ShopifyAPI::Product.count.to_f/150.0).ceil)
  products += ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:page => page, :limit => 150})
end
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
products = (1..(ShopifyAPI::Product.count.to_f/150.0).ceil).map do |page|
  ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:page => page.to_i, :limit => 150})
end
```

Which only returns the first product? What am I doing wrong?

The ShopifyAPI::Product returns a list of products based on the sent parameters page, and limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're finding the second snippet only returns the first product, but in order to make it functionally equivalent to the first, you could use `flat_map` instead of `map` here, or alternatively tack on a `.flatten` at the end (or `flatten(1)`, if you want to be more specific)

Given that the `.find` call returns an array, you can see the difference in the following examples:

```
a = []
(0..2).each { |x| a += [x] }
# a == [0,1,2]

(0..2).map { |x| [x] }
# [[0], [1], [2]]

(0..2).flat_map { |x| [x] }
# [0, 1, 2]
```

That's because `array + array` combines the two of them.

If your first snippet instead used `products.push(<find result>)` then you'd see the same nested array result.

See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map) and [Array#flatten](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten)

Comment: `(0..2).flat_map { |x| [x] }` => `(0..2).to_a`?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko yeah you're right but the question had each iteration returning arrays, so that wouldn't do it